# How to send Message only Two user in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I want when I send message to one another two will got that message like signalR groups but I doesn't use group I do this thing without group

***Please Anyone can tell  how to do that***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{
    await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

I tried with the codes in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio),just modified the codes in hub

And the result:

[image]

Send message to specific user you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0#users-in-signalr).

**Update**

I add the codes in chat.js:

```
document.getElementById("sendButton1").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("messageInput").value;
    connection.invoke("SendMessage1", user, message).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Add another button in page:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <input type="button" id="sendButton1" value="Send Message" />
</div>
```

Add this code in Hub:

```
public async Task SendMessage1(string user, string message)
{
    var a = Context.UserIdentifier;
    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I have one question can you tell me the Answer

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: how do i define all the client belong to a different method

Comment: I check when all the client of different method i send mesage from server the same message got all the client like if any client use http put they got same msg

Comment: hey can you please tell?

Comment: it use websocket by default ，you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0#transports

Comment: You could write another method in chat,js,and write another method in hub

Comment: Can you explain with some example

Comment: I've updated my answer ,please check it

Comment: And How we know client are using which one method

Comment: codes in chat.js like  connection.invoke("SendMessage1"...) invokes the  method with the same name "SendMessage1" in hub, so as your clinet receive the message，And i'm going to have  a rest,if you have other questions,i would answer you tomorrow